# Why did I receive a "serial voting was reversed" correction?

Tags: support, reputation

I read the resource [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed), but I don't believe my voting activity aligns with the described behavior:
[image]
[image]

EDIT: attached additional screenshot.

Comment: Your screenshot doesn’t display any vote correction. Did you provide the incorrect screenshot.  Only you can tell us if you serially upvotes the same person in the same day. If the user you upvotes was deleted due to THEIR actions, votes to that user, would be reversed. Care to provide more information?

Comment: You don't have any voting corrections on [su] and your link is to the [android.se] help center, did you mean to post at https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @ramhound Additional screenshot attached

Comment: The voting behaviour may well not be yours. If someone wanders onto your profile and upvotes a bunch of stuff in quick succession then you will get a reversal some time later.

Comment: @mokubai the voting correction does not enumerate which community it was for, so I assumed SU as I have more activity from there.

Comment: Ahh, I was not aware of that, if the help resource alluded to that then it went right over my head, my apologies!

Comment: The voting correction shows a community icon beside where it happened. Yours shows a small Android icon.

Comment: Sounds like a case of a user being deleted due to their actions.  Their vote was not legitimate so the vote was simply removed.